# How can i manipulate dom using a component with styled Components

Tags: javascript, reactjs, styled-components, dom-manipulation

On line 37, I'm trying to find out `OffsetTop` from elements.

When i change AnchorView to `Div` instead of View i've got. I wonder how can i manipulate dom properties of a component with styled component.

```
import React, {Component, Fragment} from 'react';
import styled from 'styled-components';
import { View } from './compoments/View'; 

class App extends Component {

handleScroll = (id) => {
   const container = this.refs.container;
   const element = this.refs[id];
   console.info('elements', this.refs);
   scrollTo(container, element, 600);
}

render() {
  return(
    <Fragment>
    <Container ref="container">
      {Test.map((index) => <AnchorItem key={index+1} ref={'anchor'+index} id= . 
      {'anchor'+index}>{index}</AnchorItem>)}
    </Container>
    <Menu>
      <input type="button" value="input" onClick={() => this.handleScroll('anchor0')} />
      <input type="button" value="input" onClick={() => this.handleScroll('anchor1')} />
      <input type="button" value="input" onClick={() => this.handleScroll('anchor3')} />
      <input type="button" value="input" onClick={() => this.handleScroll('anchor4')} />
    </Menu>
  </Fragment>
    )
  };
}


 const Container = styled('div')`
    margin: 40px auto;
    height: 150px;
    width: 600px;
    border: 1px solid black;
    overflow: auto;
        `;

 const AnchorItem = styled(View)`
    margin: auto;
    height: 200px;
    width: 500px;
    border: 1px solid black;
    overflow: auto;
    height: 80px;
    background: blue;
    list-style: none;
    margin:.5rem;
    color: white;
`;

const Menu = styled('div')`
    margin: 50px auto;
    width: 600px;
    height: 50px;
`;

export default App;
`
```

Anybody could help me? thanks in advance.

Comment: Hello @almir-júnior, line 37 says `border: 1px solid black;` so I guess that is not the line where you want to find an OffsetTop. You're asking multiple question here which makes it kind of hard to come up with an answer. When I'm in those kind of situations, I'm trying to come up with a simple example, rather than my real code. Could you maybe try to simplify your question?

Comment: fixed text style